# Issue receiving/displaying push notification from Android Cordova mobile app

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

My small company has developed a mobile app which uses push notifications. All is developed using Cordova framework, and for years everything seemed to work well. Some years ago we have been forced to switch to FCM to send iOS and android notifications, and now we noticed that a lot of notifications are not shown to the target devices. We have a big number of users, 50-80k, so it is not easy knowing how many, but I've done some test sendings and I've noticed that, on my test device, after the closure of application, very often the notifications never arrives. Some notifications arrive though, especially if I send it some minutes after closing the app. But if the device stays idle for a long time, the notifications fails to be displayed on the device.

All notifications are taken from FCM with success response, so the problem must be device/client side. Moreover, it seems that when app is open notification always arrives and it's shown in the app. When app is in background, but minimized, issues are less frequent. When app is swiped away, so closed, issues are more frequent.

Probably there are some crashes of the app, because I see a lot of issue from FCM console Crashlitics. All crashes are in the initial startup of the app (< 1 sec from user session) and all in due to GCMBroadcastReceiver, for example:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start receiver com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver:
> android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to
> start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
> flg=0x1000010 pkg=it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile
> cmp=it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile/com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
> (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{66f80ac u0a266 RCVR
> idle change:idle|uncached procs:0 seq(0,0,0)}
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4770)
>
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
>
> Caused by android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException Not
> allowed to start service Intent {
> act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010
> pkg=it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile
> cmp=it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile/com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
> (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{66f80ac u0a266 RCVR
> idle change:idle|uncached procs:0 seq(0,0,0)}
> android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1941)
>
> com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive
> (GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:55)
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4761)
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:310)
>
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)

There are different crashes but all from GCMBroadcastReceiver, and all related to start intent. All are in the first seconds of user session, but I'm not expert in Cordova architecture, nor in android mobile app, that's the reason we chose to develop it using Cordova, so we can replicate part of our javascript code used in existing web-app.

Cordova AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="103000001" android:versionName="1030" package="it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" />
        <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/accent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileOpener2.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/opener_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="it.caleidoscopio.avisnetmobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>
```

Cordova version is 11.0, Android platform is 8.0, and notifications on iOS seem to work like a charm

Thank you for your patience to everyone could help me.